# Problems looking up a WebLogic 12c EJB3 beans from a remote application

Tags: java, weblogic12c, ejb-3.1

I am

- using Java 7
- using WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.3.0.0 (12c)
- have a set of EJB3 beans as part of a deployed EAR file
- just using @Stateless annotation on my beans
- able to see the beans in the JNDI view (e.g. java:global.ifactory.ifactory-ejb-4.0.0.BomServiceBean!com.icumed.ifactory3.service.BomServiceRemote)
- running a command-line app which is trying to access those EJBs
- am using wlthint3client.jar
- have disabled IIOP

However, I cannot access the bean when I have "java:global" (I get NameNotFoundException: remaining name...) and I only get slightly further without it. It still fails on lookup with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.getEnvQueriedJNDITimeout(StubInfo.java:256)
...
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:426)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
```

What am I missing or have wrong?

Comment: According to a webpage from Oracle, "Unpublished WLS Bug 20755176: According to this bug "ClassCastException thrown from weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.getEnvQueriedJNDITimeout()" is generated when the "weblogic.jndi.responseReadTimeout" property has a String value in jndi properties." However, I've tried to set that and any other timeout value in jndi.properties to numeric values, but the outcome has been the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the code of wlthint3client.jar (StubInfo.java). The following two properties do not get converted properly from String to Long if you specify them in the jndi.properties file.

```
Long o = (Long)props.get("weblogic.jndi.responseReadTimeout");

if (o == null) {
  o = (Long)props.get("weblogic.rmi.clientTimeout");
}
```

If you need to set these properties you will have to create a Hashtable in your code and pass that to the InitialContext.

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

env.put("weblogic.jndi.responseReadTimeout", 15000L);
env.put("weblogic.rmi.clientTimeout", 15000L);
```